# Can I use the sudoers function without enabling the suid bit?

Tags: security

I mounted all my FS with nosuid option and removed the suid/sgid bit from all my files.

The question: It looks like I breaked sudo. It doesn't work anymore, no matter what I try to set in /etc/sudoers. Is this normal that sudo needs suid bit, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to switch to an arbitrary user / group without superuser access. Utilities like `su` and `sudo` switch to root via the suid bit and then enforce whatever privilege system they're designed to provide. It's unlikely that there were any files with a suid/sgid bit that didn't require it, so you broke stuff across the board. There are probably still binaries using capabilities (setcap) rather than a coarse suid to root anyway (like `ping`) although `nosuid` will stop them from working too.

It's true that suid binaries are a security risk because getting code execution via a vulnerability inside one of these tools will elevate privileges outside of their security model. However, it's there for a reason...